# Generating a random list of (x, y) points that satisfy a condition?

Tags: matlab, random, 2d

So I need to generate a matrix of x and y points given that they meet the condition that at these (x,y) points concentration is greater than 10. Note that I first run a code that gives me concentration at each location, and now I need Matlab to "randomly" pick (x,y) points with the above condition.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your data looks something like this :

```
data= [...  x  y  concentration
            1, 1, 1; ...
            2, 1, 11; ...
            1, 2, 12; ...
            2, 2, 1 ...
    ]
```

You could find all concentrations bigger than 10 with:

```
data_cbigger10=data(data(:,3)>10,:) % using logical indexing
```

and choose a random point from there with:

```
randomPoint=data_cbigger10(ceil(size(data_cbigger10,2)*rand),:) % pick a random index
```

---

If the dimensions are as follows:

> the dimension of concentration is 52x61x61 as concentration is c(x,y,time), that of x is 1x61 and 1x52 for y. @PetrH –  s2015

this should do the trick:

This is your data, I just make something up:

```
x=linspace(0,1,61);
y=linspace(0,1,52);
con=20*rand(61,52);
```

Now I find all positions in con which are bigger than 10. This results in a logical matrix. By multipling it with an random matrix the same size I get a matrix with random values where 'con' is bigger than 10, but everywhere else equals zero.

```
data_cbigger10=rand(size(con)).*(con>10);
```

by finding the max, or min, Value a random point is choosen:

```
for n=1:1:10
    data_cbigger10=rand(size(con)).*(con>10);

    [vals,xind]=max(data_cbigger10);
    xind=squeeze(xind);
    [vals,yind]=max(squeeze(vals));
    [~,time_ind]=max(squeeze(vals));

    yind=yind(time_ind);
    xind=xind(yind,time_ind);
    x_res(n)=x(xind)
    y_res(n)=y(yind)
    time_res(n)=time(time_ind)
    con_res(n)=con(xind,yind,time_ind)
    con(xind,yind,time_ind)=0; % setting the choosen point to zero, so it will not be choosen again.
end
```

Hope this works now for you.

Comment: @macro This works, but I get only 1D data. My concentration changes with both the x and y directions, c(i,j), so at the end I need 2D data points. Any idea how I can generate the same for both x(i) and y(j)? Thanks!

Comment: well the 'randomPoint' should be a [1x3] vector with 'x=randomPoint(1)', 'y=randomPoint(2)' and 'concentration=randomPoint(3)'. Try it again, corrected an error: 'randomPoint=**data_cbigger10**(round(size(data_cbigger10,2)*rand),:)'

Comment: "randomPoint=**data_cbigger10**(round(size(data_cbigger10,2)*rand),:)" Should I remove the "**'? Anyways, when I run: "randomPoint=data_cbigger10(round(size(data_cbigger10,2)*rand),:)" I get the following error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." @marco

Comment: @s2015 just saw your comment to PetrH, made the same assumption as he did. Will change answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the help, but when I run "[row,col]=find(data_cbigger10==max(max(data_cbigger10))); ", I get the following error "Error using  == 
Array dimensions must match for binary array op." @marco

Comment: @s2015 yeah, sorry, I missed the time fixed it

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly fine. My question is what if instead of finding only one random point, I'm interested in generating a number of random points, say 10 random points for example? Is there any way other than finding the maximum or minimum points? @marco

Comment: @s2015 first thing that springs to mind is a for loop, ther migth be a more elegant solution. but i do not see it rigth now. see edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the concentration for each point `(x,y)` stored in an array `concentration` you can use the `find()` and `randsample()` functions like so:

```
conGT10 = find(concentration>10);    % find where concentration is greater than 10 (gives you indices)
randomPoints = randsample(conGT10,nn);    % choose nn random numbers from those that satisfy the condition
x1 = x(randomPoints);     % given the randomly drawn indices pull the corresponding numbers for x and y
y1 = y(randomPoints);
```

---

**EDIT:** 
The above assumes that arrays `x`, `y`, and `concentration` are `1d` and of the same length. Apparently this is not true for your problem.

You have a grid of points on a `(x,y)` plane and you measure concentration on this grid in different time periods. So the length of `x` is `nx`, the length of `y` is `ny` and the size of `concentration` is `nx` by `ny` by `nt`. For simplicity I will assume that you measure concentration only once, i.e. `nt=1` and concentration is only `2d` array.

The modified version of my previous answer would then be as follows:

```
[rows,cols] = find(concentration>10);    % find where concentration is greater than 10 (gives you indices)
randomIndices = randsample(length(rows),nn);    % choose nn random integers from 1 to n, where n is the number of observations that satisfy the condition 'concentration>10'
randomX = x(rows(randomIndices));
randomY = y(cols(randomIndices));
```

Comment: I've tried it, but I'm getting this error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." when I try to run the x1 and y1 commands. Could it be because my concentration varies with both the x and y; c(i,j)? @PetrH

Comment: @s2015 My solution assumes `x`, `y` and `concentration` are 1d arrays of the same length. If they are not then I may not fully understand what you do.

Comment: the dimension of concentration is 52x61x61 as concentration is c(x,y,time), that of x is 1x61 and  1x52 for y. @PetrH

Comment: @s2015 Now I understand what you do. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." error when I run "randomX = x(rows(randomIndices))" @PetrH

Comment: @s2015 I am not receiving that error and after quick testing the code seems to provide correct answer.

Comment: @s2015 I have got an idea, it is a speculation but theoretically it could explain the error you observe. On line 2 of my code there is a typo `row` should be `rows`. When you run the code Matlab throws an error (different from yours) that `row` has not been defined. If you however had a variable `row` in your workspace accidentally then it might throw the error you observe. I will edit my answer to fix the typo.

Comment: Matlab detected the typo when I tried to run it, but I still got the error of index exceeding the matrix dimensions.

Comment: @s2015 Now I see what is wrong. You have `x` and `y` swapped, i.e. `x` runs across columns and `y` runs across rows. I naturally assumed the opposite and did not check too carefully the dimensions you provided (the other answer did the same thus it yields incorrect results). To fix that either swap the names of the `x` and `y` vectors in your main code (recommended) or swap `rows` for `cols` on lines 3 and 4 of my code (i.e. `randomX = x(cols(randomIndices));` and `randomY = y(rows(randomIndices));`)

Comment: The randomY command "randomY = y(rows(randomIndices));" worked and I get zeros (1x50), but the randomX "randomX = x(cols(randomIndices));" still gives me the same error message. "[rows,cols] = find(concentration>10); % find where concentration is greater than 10 (gives you indices)" when I run this, the results are stored in cols and rows, both have dimensions of 1369x1. Then, when I run "randomIndices=randsample(length(rows),nn);" for nn=50, the size of the results is 50x1. @PetrH

Comment: @s2015 This all sounds OK (except the zeros, why do you get zeros? Check what is inside `y` and `x`). As long as `nn` is less then the number of points satisfying the condition it should work. Check the size of the input arrays. Is it really the case that `length(y) == size(concentration,1)` and `length(x) == size(concentration,2)`? If they are it must work. Also check `min(randomIndices)` and `max(randomIndices)`. They must be between 1 and 1369 (and I bet they are). Similarly `rows` and `cols` must be between 1 and 52 and 61 respectively.

Comment: "size(concentration,1)" gives 52 which is length(y), and the same when I run "size(concentration,2)" I get 61 which is length(x). min(randomIndices)=25 and max(randomIndices)=1293 which as you said are between 1 and 1369. The results stored in rows and those stored in cols both have sizes of 1369x1. The values in rows range from 1-3, and those in cols range from 2-3039. My x-values range from -2.5 m to 9242 m, while those of y range from 0-9242 m. @PetrH

Comment: @s2015 `cols` is wrong. I made the assumption that `concentration` is a 2d array while you seem to be running it with `concentration` being 3d. Then `cols` picks the 3rd dimension as well.

Comment: That's true. I'm running it for the case of c being 3D. @PetrH